# Unable to run java flight recorder on JRE 9

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jfr

my java home is set to JRE9

i am trying to run flight recorder on a jar , but it throws error below

```
[0.109s][error][jfr,system] jdk.jfr not found.
[0.109s][error][jfr,system] Java Flight Recorder can not be enabled.
```

Could it be beacuse of JRE 9 i am using at runtime?

Comment: read https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRRT164

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a modular image of the JDK that doesn't include the jdk.jfr module.

Use the full Oracle JDK, or create a modular image with JFR included.

```
jlink --add-modules jdk.jfr   ...
```

If you want to connect to JFR over JMX, i.e. start and stop recordings from JMC:

```
jlink --add-modules jdk.management.jfr   ...
```